# DateTime.Compare() is returning 1 on identical DateTimes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've been working on a getting messages via EntityFramwork 6.

Basically I have an API that I pass a date into then I use EntityFramework to get the latest message.

Now when I use DateTime.Compare(date1, date2) The result is 1 which is not correct as the dates are identical.

You can see in this image:

[image]

The dates are the same but testd = 1

Any ideas why this would happen?

Here's the code:

```
var result = ChatProvider
                .GetAllChatsForUser(memberUser.UserName)
                .Where(x => x.FromUser.Equals(lastMessage.FromUser)).OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeCreated).LastOrDefault();

            var testd = DateTime.Compare(result.DateTimeCreated, Date);
```

Thanks!

Comment: We can't see that the values are identical in the image - we can only see as far as the seconds. My guess is that they have different subsecond values. Try looking at the `Ticks` property of each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft's [Reference Source for DateTime.Compare](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,565) shows (stating at line 565)

```
public static int Compare(DateTime t1, DateTime t2) {
    Int64 ticks1 = t1.InternalTicks;
    Int64 ticks2 = t2.InternalTicks;
    if (ticks1 > ticks2) return 1;
    if (ticks1 < ticks2) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

This confirms Jon Skeet's assumption, that there must be a sub second difference. In particular, no other information like `DateTimeKind` is considered.

You could round to the desired precision prior to the comparison with this function (but of course this does not work with EF and has to be done on the client side).

```
private DateTime Round(DateTime dt, TimeSpan precision)
{
    return new DateTime(((dt.Ticks + precision.Ticks/2) / precision.Ticks) * precision.Ticks);
}
```

Use like this

```
var oneSecond = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
var testd = DateTime.Compare(
    Round(result.DateTimeCreated, oneSecond),
    Round(Date, oneSecond));
```

Comment: I changed the code to pass in the ticks rather than the date, then used your Compare method. Thanks!!!

Comment: Note, that's not my compare method. It's the built in `DateTime.Compare` method  from Microsoft. What I suggest, is to apply my round method to both of the dates before doing the comparison.

Comment: Ahh yeah just looked. Rushing too much! I've updated the code to do the standard compare after converting the ticks to a DateTime and it works. Thanks!